# Facebook Like/Send data-href vs. og:url Pickle

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want users to be able to use the facebook send button to send friends a link to a page on my site. The page itself is the generic sign-up page, but if there is a "referral_code" query string parameter it indicates who referred the user. In that sense, the URL is unique, even though the page is not. So, I do the following on a page called /referrals (with the jssdk already loaded):

```
<span class="fb-send" data-href="http://my.domain.com/sign_up?referral_code=unique-to-each-user"></span>
```

The send button opens the dialog correctly, but it is including a lame image and text in the message using whatever selection heuristic facebook engineers have built.

I read a little further in the docs and find I can use og:image on the /sign_up page to specify the image to use (as long as the width/height ration is < 3!).

So, on http://my.domain.com/sign_up I add the requisite og tags.

The **pickle**: if you use **any** og tags then you **must** also include og:url, and it seems that og:url takes precedence.

My question, then, is, am I right that og:url takes precedence over data-href? And if so, is there some other technique I can use that allows me to include the og tags on the target page (static) while still specifying the exact URL (dynamic) to send/like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that Facebook will take the value of the OG:url over what is provided as data-href.

However the ref attribute should do what you want.  From the send button docs:

> ref - a label for tracking referrals; must be less than 50 characters
>   and can contain alphanumeric characters and some punctuation
>   (currently +/=-.:_). The ref attribute causes two parameters to be
>   added to the referrer URL when a user clicks a link from a stream
>   story about a Send action:

So if you provide the ref attribute in your send button code the referral id will be added to the incoming url:

```
<fb:send data-href="http://my.domain.com/signup" ref="unique-to-each-user"></fb:send>
```

The above code would produce this as the URL in the stream story:

> http://www.yoursite.com/sign-up?fb_ref=unique-to-each-user&fb_source=message

When clicked through to your site you could grab the value of fb_ref and determine which user provided the referral.